# How to give an item with two data tags

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm not particularly sure whether or not their called "Data tags", but on with the question! I wanted to be able to give myself a tripwire hook that has a custom name AND a CanDestroy tag as well. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The give command is not limited to 1 nbt tag.

```
 /give @p minecraft:tripwire_hook 0 1   {display:{Name:"name here",color:,Lore:["lore here", "lore here"]},CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone","minecraft:stonebrick"]}
```